# flatten a binary tree into a linked list with rotations

Tags: linked-list, binary-search-tree, nodes, transformation, children

i want to flatten a binary tree and transforme it into a linked list using rotations. we should have two types of linked lists, the first type is when all the nodes are in the left side ,ie: our tree will only have left children  and all the right children will become NULL , we ll do this type of transformation by  doing a left rotation to all the nodes that have a right child.
the second type is to have a tree that only  have right childs with the left childs set to NULL, we do such transformation by doing a right rotation for all the nodes that have a left child. tha
i didn't know how to write the algorithme of this transformation although i tried a lot, i just need the algorithme of this transformation or the code in C.
here's the data structure:

```
 typedef struct Tib Type_Tib  ;
  typedef Type_Tib * Typestr_Tib ;
  typedef int Type1_Tib  ;
  typedef bool Type2_Tib  ;
  struct Tib
    {
      Type1_Tib Champ1 ;
      Type2_Tib Champ2 ;
    };

  Type1_Tib Struct1_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S)
    {
      return  S->Champ1 ;
    }

  Type2_Tib Struct2_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S)
    {
      return  S->Champ2 ;
    }

  void Aff_struct1_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S, Type1_Tib Val )
    {
       S->Champ1 = Val ;
    }

  void Aff_struct2_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S, Type2_Tib Val )
    {
       S->Champ2 = Val ;
    }


  /** Arbres de recherche binaire **/

  typedef Typestr_Tib Typeelem_ATib   ;
  typedef struct Noeud_ATib * Pointeur_ATib ;

  struct Noeud_ATib
    {
      Typeelem_ATib  Val ;
      Pointeur_ATib Fg ;
      Pointeur_ATib Fd ;
      Pointeur_ATib Pere ;
     } ;
```

hope you can help me because i REALLY need this algorithme.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for questions that show an effort, and are about a *specific* problem encountered with that effort.

Comment: Did the class teach how to do a rotate? For a right rotate: temp = node.left, node.left = node.right, node.right = node, node = temp. You'll need additional variables and code to do this to an entire tree. It will be simpler if you use a dummy node: NODE dummy, dummy.left = null, dummy.right = root. When finished, return dummy.right.